# Old question with links to resources has been deleted

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

An old question [Cocoa and Objective-C resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571/cocoa-and-objective-c-resources) (2008) has been correctly closed because off-topic (2013) but recently (March 2015) it has been deleted. Its main value is to collect links to learning resources about Objective-C (note: I did not write that post and I do not have any answer there).

I completely agree it's off-topic and it has to be consequently closed (even if it was tolerated on early times) but it has a relatively high number of views (~45000) and some high upvoted answers. Moreover same type of posts has not been deleted (thankfully!) for example [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1207195), [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/1207195) and [Delphi = Pascal? Resources for Learning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1149238/1207195).

That deleted question was even linked in wiki for [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) (see also [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10608991) to remove it).

Then my question is: should this question be undeleted? If not then what to do with other similar posts? Is there rule to eventually vote to delete them or it's left to mods' discretion?

Comment: If undeleted, it should be locked by a moderator (like the C book list) to prevent future VLQ answers.

Comment: I agree, anyone with 10k rep can lock a question (if I'm not wrong)

Comment: 15k users can [protect a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) (needs 10 rep on site to answer), but only mods can add historical locks (which prevent voting/answering/commenting/editing).

Comment: you  are  right !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked for a [wiki answer lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182566/this-lock-notice-is-partly-misleading/182572#182572) on [Good resources for learning Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374660/good-resources-for-learning-objective-c)* a while back so that we (Objective-C/Cocoa people) would have one of these to keep around. That had always seemed to be the best of this breed to me. I don't think we really need multiples, but it is good to have one to use as a duplicate target.

I've been keeping my eye on the answer for dead links or other problems (it doesn't require much upkeep, fortunately), and I welcome company in that stewardship -- which stewardship is, to me, implicitly part of the justification for the lock. Please feel free to import good links from the deleted question, or from other places.

Also, note that "resources for learning about the tag's subject" is one of the explicit purposes of the tag wiki, so the links could also go there directly. The only disadvantage to this is that the wiki cannot be used to close a new "What book should I read?" question as a duplicate.

---

*And flagged it for un-deletion in March, the same time the one you link was deleted.

Comment: OK, it seems they have been delete by same mod, well I guess he was doing some housekeeping! Then we may link tag wiki to survived post (unfortunately I can't help more, I found this just reviewing edits queue).